# Woocommerce Product Variations attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Question regarding Product attributes.

Generally Products attributes display in a `drop down`, when you select attribute from the `drop down` it will show an `add to cart` button. This is the Woo-commerce default flow of attributes.

Now my question is that I don't like to display attributes in a select box. I would like to display as my layout.

For example, we have size attributes in Product and that will display in the select box, but I want to display in circle designs. I don't want to display as a `drop down`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. you can get all your product variations using 
`$product->get_available_variations()` It'll return an array containing all your product variation data. When user selects an option woocommerce updating an input value with the selection. It's a hidden input in your source. You need to find that input field and update it's value. I normally use jquery for that.

Hope it'll help.

Thanks.